# Fb not providing Login info to users that are not listed in app's role as admin or tester

Tags: android

I have a confusable situation here. In my android app, I am using Fb login and SDK.Things work fine when fb native app is not present.But when fb app is there and login is done then FB provides info only when I logged on with native FB app and not when somebody else logins. The screen just flashes once and goes away. I have also found that roles that are listed in app on fb including me (admin) & testers are able to fetch information, but not the other normal users. I have tried but I dont know where the fault is happening? 
thanks.

```
  public void signInWithFacebook() {

    Constant.printKeyHash(MainActivity.this);
    mSessionTracker = new SessionTracker(mContext, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        }
    }, null, false);

    String applicationId = Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(mContext);
    Constant.mCurrentSession = mSessionTracker.getSession();

    if (Constant.mCurrentSession == null || Constant.mCurrentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        mSessionTracker.setSession(null);
        Session session = new Session.Builder(mContext).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        Constant.mCurrentSession = session;
    } else {
        mSessionTracker.setSession(null);
        Session session = new Session.Builder(mContext).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        Constant.mCurrentSession = session;
    }

    if (!Constant.mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
        openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) mContext);

        if (openRequest != null) {
            openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
            openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday", "email", "user_location", "user_friends"));
            openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);

            Constant.mCurrentSession.openForRead(openRequest);

            try {
               // progressfb.show();
               // progressfb.setCancelable(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            accessFacebookUserInfo();
        }
    } else {

       // progressfb.show();
        accessFacebookUserInfo();

    }
}


   public void accessFacebookUserInfo() {
 if (Session.getActiveSession() != null ||                              Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fields", "picture,email,first_name, last_name, name");
        //  bundle.putString("fields", "email");
        // bundle.putString("fields", "first_name");

        final Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me", bundle, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                if (graphObject != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                        jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();

                        Log.i("", "faacebook response===" + jsonObject.toString());

                        String facebook_id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                        JSONObject picture_obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("picture");
                        JSONObject picture_data = picture_obj.getJSONObject("data");

                        // fb_pic_url = picture_data.getString("url");

                        String first_name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        String last_name = jsonObject.getString("last_name");
                        String socialName = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        eemail = jsonObject.getString("email");

                        String fb_pic_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"
                                + facebook_id
                                + "/picture?type=large";

                new fbSigninActivity().execute(eemail,first_name);
                        callFacebookLogout(MainActivity.this);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       // com.facebook.Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (Constant.mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {

            accessFacebookUserInfo();

        } else {
            //Utils.showCenterToast(contxt, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_went_wrong));
        }
    } else {
        Constant.mCurrentSession = null;
        mSessionTracker.setSession(null);
      //  progressfb.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code you include the specific code you are using that might be the source of the problem (please only include relevant/specific code)?

Comment: I have using the above code pasted here, I have tried but I am still getting info of testers and dev only when fb app is install.as soon as I remove any tester,func is not able to fetch information. Any help will be appreciated.thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because the feature you are trying to use needs to be approved by Facebook first. You must submit an APK for them to test. Anyone listed as an Admin, Developer, or Tester of your app should work fine (you may need to add their debug hash of the device to the list). But until your app gets approved by Facebook to use specific features or Graph Calls normal users will NOT be able to use it.

Comment: Could you please provide me any link related to this.It will be helpful

Comment: Also want to know that do I have to provide apk to fb for approval, as you said above??

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature  There is a link for Feature review guidelines and more info on that. This has a list of features that need to be submitted for review with an APK of your app before people who are not listed as Developers, Admins, or Testers in your console can use them.

Comment: Since I only need email information, why do I have to submit my app for review in this case ? secondly, when a tester or admin loggged in, fb fetches info automatically then why not a normal user could do that thing.